# How to check whether two bounding boxes are overlapping in a frame ? [OpenCV]

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am a noob and trying to learn OpenCV, I am working on a mini project which triggers certain functions if a person is detected in a specific area of the frame marked with a bounding box, can somebody guide how can I check whether a bounding box [ i.e detected object/person ] is overlapping with an already drawn bounding box[ i.e bounding box specified on a certain position of screen ] are overlapping?

Comment: How do you have the bounding boxes stored?

Comment: Bounding boxes from the objects will be returned by YOLO.

Comment: But do you have the corners? My question is how are they stored, not where they come from.

Comment: YOLO style bounding boxes are in `x,y,w,h` format with `x,y` being the top left corner of the box and `w,h` being the width and height.  The duplicate linked by Miki should be more than sufficient to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV python you'll have to implement this by hand. Check [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/90455/how-to-perform-intersection-or-union-operations-on-a-rect-in-python/) for an implementation example.